# make a rectangle move in a different thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
{

    int x, y = 10;

    Graphics g;

    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = this.CreateGraphics();

        System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(threadmethod);

        th.Start();            
    }

    void threadmethod()
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Interval = 100;
        t.Tick += T_Tick;
    }

    private void T_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Blue), new Rectangle(x++, y++, 20, 20));
    }
}
```

a rectangle is animated when this code is run without threading. But rectangle isn't animated or drawn in this code. please let me know changes i should make

Comment: it's not your fault that you don't know how to do multithreading. But Stack Overflow isn't the place to learn, well, anything any more, unless it's a simple question with a clearly defined scope capable of a simple answer. What you need is a tutorial in multithreading in C#, so try searching youtube for that. Or go to university and pay for your own education.

Comment: @PeterWone "But Stack Overflow isn't the place to learn, " I strongly disagree. Furthermore I don't really understand the downvotes. "unless it's a simple question with a clearly defined scope capable of a simple answer." look at the post. It has everything that one needs. 1) a simple question with a clearly defined scope. It has the entire code to reproduce the problem. just copy paste it as SO requires. In itself it is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PeterWone and 2)  "clearly defined scope capable of a simple answer." => the answer is fairly simple. With 360 characters you could have written down an plausible answer for this problem instead of suggesting to OP to "go to university and pay for your own education."

Comment: @PeterWone the only point that I could agree here with you is that the shows a great lack of research. That is indeed true. But the question is neither ill placed here not is it too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong timer. The [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is made to run on the UI thread.

> This Windows timer is designed for a single-threaded environment where UI threads are used to perform processing.

Your rectangle is not drawn because the `Tick` event is never fired!

Solution: Use instead a timer that is made to run in the background:

[System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is a possible cadidate. Change our code simply to this:

```
void threadmethod()
{
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
    t.Enabled = true;
    t.Interval = 100;
    t.Elapsed += T_Tick;
    t.AutoReset = true;
}
```

and the rest can remain as it is and you can see your blue rectangle creep over your GUI surface

Comment: thanks. it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like your thread doesn't know about the UI thread, you need to invoke your drawing method to the UI thread. Something like:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Blue), 
new Rectangle(x++, y++, 20, 20)); });
```